# all folders (Desktop, downloads, documents etc) on Win7 guest render unavailable after dropping a file from Host machine

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-error-reporting

Almost any folders in my VM Windows 7 Home directory rendered unavailable (showing up error message) on click on any folder, after I dropped a file from Host machine to guest (VM). What is this exactly?

The error was exactly like this one:

[enter link description here](https://www.wintips.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/image-26.png)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Some screen shots would help us understand your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new User account, and running VM from there? Place the files/folder from the Administrator documents into the new User documents folder...